# Is StackOveflow running asp.net MVC2 + SQL Server?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I just a couple of tweets that got my attention.

This one

> [Digg: 200MM page views, 500 servers. Stack Overflow: 60MM page views, 5 servers. What am I missing?](http://twitter.com/spolsky/status/27244766467)

and then this one

> [(nb Stack Overflow is ASP.NET MVC + SQL Server, Digg was LAMP)](http://twitter.com/spolsky/status/27245509523)

Is this true? how can that be? there has to be some kind of error in digg's architecture, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which tools and technologies were used to build the Trilogy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy)

Comment: While this question is a dupe of the FAQ question, Stack Exchange is migrating to a new data center very soon, so the content in that question will be out of date as soon as the move is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack Overflow does in fact run on ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy). I don't think there's anything wrong with Digg's LAMP implementation per se; they just did it differently.

Answer (score 1):

I hoped it would run on Ruby since [All The Cool Kids Use Ruby](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GpOfwbFRcs)

Answer (score 1):

You assume scaling is linear.  It is not.  Crap happens when it doesn't fit in memory anymore.  Happened about 1 1/2 months ago, as near as I can tell, without *any* proof beyond the previously-remarkable-perf from the /reputation link and the lack of spinners.

And losing some of my favorite queries, got the lolcats several times on my customized tag rep queries.  Sorry for that btw guys, I know SQL query timeouts suck.

Scaling is tough, I trust these guys to get it right.  Even if it does suck mud once in a while.  Great job, this *has* to be hard.